# How to list source filename of matching searches wth ripgrep/fzf

Tags: fuzzy-search, fzf

### problem

I need to search a directory of textfiles, where the contents of the files is searched too. I am currently using ripgrep and fzf to do this - the problem is that each line of each file outputs the search. **I need each search match to also indicate its source filename/filepath.**

### Example:

We have following two files:

#### example.md

> something something foo something
>
> something something foo something
>
> something something foo something
>
> something something foo something

#### useful-example.md

> something something foo something

We run `rg . | fzf` in the directory containing them, write foo, and get following results:

> useful-example.md:something something **foo** something
>
> example.md:something something **foo** something
>
> example.md:something something **foo** something
>
> example.md:something something **foo** something
>
> example.md:something something **foo** something

The problem here is that each line of example.md is a search result. It should be a match referring to its file. It should have looked something like this:

> useful-example.md:something something **foo** something
>
> example.md:something something **foo** something
>
> ......................something **foo** something
>
> ......................something **foo** something
>
> ......................something **foo** something

Answer (score 5):

Ripgrep comes which a `--heading` flag that (from the man page)

> prints the file path above clusters of matches from each file
> instead of printing the file path as a prefix for each matched line

It looks like this:

```
rg --heading --line-number --column . | fzf --layout=reverse

useful-example.txt
1:1:something something foo something

example.txt
1:1:something something foo something
2:1:something something foo something
3:1:something something foo something
4:1:something something foo something
```

If you are only interested in files with matches, add the flag `--files-with-matches`:

```
rg --files-with-matches . | fzf
useful-example.txt
example.txt
```